# two-way-gridview inside a LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, gridview, android-studio

I'm having a few issues getting the Two Way Gridview library (originally by Jess Andres https://github.com/jess-anders/two-way-gridview ) to work in a LinearLayout.

Jess' example code just has the gridview in the layout xml by itself, however I need to add additional elements around the gridview hence have put the element and the gridview inside a LinearLayout.
The issue is that I'm getting the following error...

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.AbsListView$LayoutParams cannot be cast to two_way_gridview_gradle.TwoWayAbsListView$LayoutParams
        at two_way_gridview_gradle.TwoWayGridView$HorizontalGridBuilder.onMeasure(TwoWayGridView.java:2872)
        at two_way_gridview_gradle.TwoWayGridView.onMeasure(TwoWayGridView.java:286)
```

I understand that the issue is that the inflator is attempting to assign parameters from TwoWayAbsList to the LinearLayout parameters, but I haven't a clue as to how to force it to use only the TwoWayAbsListView parameters

Here's my layout file....

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/caller_text"
            android:layout_width="174dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
            android:lines="2"
            android:textSize="17sp"
            android:text="First text block"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"/>

    <two_way_gridview_gradle.TwoWayGridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/gridview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="#E8E8E8"
        app:cacheColorHint="#E8E8E8"
        app:columnWidth="80dp"
        app:rowHeight="80dp"
        app:gravity="center"
        app:horizontalSpacing="16dp"
        app:verticalSpacing="16dp"
        app:numColumns="auto_fit"
        app:numRows="auto_fit"
        app:scrollDirectionLandscape="horizontal"
        app:scrollDirectionPortrait="horizontal"
        app:stretchMode="spacingWidthUniform"
        />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/cancel_text"
            android:layout_width="174dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
            android:lines="2"
            android:textSize="17sp"
            android:text="Second text block"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

And here's how I'm inflating the view in the activity onCreate() method....

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_meetingcaller);
TwoWayGridView gridView = (TwoWayGridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
// Instance of ImageAdapter Class
gridView.setAdapter(new GridImageAdapter(this));
```

Comment: you have already set the layout height and width in xml. then why again setting in you code `gridView.setLayoutParams(...)`?

Comment: your problem is in `gridView.setLayoutParams(..)`

Comment: that was my attempt to force the parameter types to TwoWayAbsListView when inflating the layout. I've updated the post to remove that call, and show the different error message (which is still a cast issue)

Comment: Solved! @Rustam was close, infact it was this line in my GridImageAdapter that was causing the issue        `imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(70, 70));`

Answer (score 0):

I have been messing around to implement Two-way gridview, but finally implemented it my way:

```
<ScrollView
                android:id="@+id/mainscrolView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                >


                <HorizontalScrollView
                    android:id="@+id/rclv"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    >

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        >



                        <TableLayout
                            android:id="@+id/table"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:stretchColumns="*"
                            >

                        </TableLayout>
                    </LinearLayout>
                </HorizontalScrollView>
</ScrollView>
```

I add the children of TableLayout programmatically. Like:

```
TableLayout tv =  findViewById(R.id.table);
 tv.removeAllViewsInLayout();

 TableRow tr = new TableRow(AndroidDatabaseManager.this);

 tr.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                        LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                        LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
 TextView b3 = new TextView(AndroidDatabaseManager.this);
b3.setText("Child");
tr.addView(b3);

 tv.addView(tr);

                final View vline = new View(AndroidDatabaseManager.this);
                vline.setLayoutParams(new
                        TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,2));
                vline.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
                tv.addView(vline);
```

If you want to add border to cells. There's a little workaround for it.